# Display result in desired area

Tags: jquery, css

I just want a quick test my code. I want to display the result in a desired area.

There is a button, I want to click the button to display something. Currently I just use alert for test.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btn1').click(myFunction);
    });
    function myFunction() {
        $('#res1').alert('hi');
    }
```

My CSS:

```
#btn1 {
position: relative;
width: 50px;
height: 25px;
margin-left: 90px;
margin-top: 10px;
background-color: #008080;
}

#res1 {
position: relative;
width: 550px;
height: 550px;
}
```

Html is quite simple:

```
<div id="btn1">Send</div>
<div id="res1"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to add a text to the res1 div? Here's how:

```
function myFunction() {
    $('#res1').text('hi');
}
```

You can also add html.

```
function myFunction() {
    $('#res1').html('hi');
}
```

Comment: later on I will use ajax call web service, is it similar?

Comment: Yes, you can pass the result of the ajax requests to the text or html like this: `$('#res1').text(result);`

Answer (score 0):

why not use

> $("#res1").text("h1")

which will add text to your #res1